# How to add totals as well as group_by statistics in R

Tags: r, dplyr, split-apply-combine

When computing any statistic using `summarise` and `group_by` we only get the summary statistic per-category, and not the value for all the population (Total). How to get both?

I am looking for something clean and short. Until now I can only think of:

```
bind_rows( 
  iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(
    "Mean" = mean(Sepal.Width), 
    "Median" = median(Sepal.Width), 
    "sd" = sd(Sepal.Width), 
    "p10" = quantile(Sepal.Width, probs = 0.1))
  , 
  iris %>% summarise(
    "Mean" = mean(Sepal.Width), 
    "Median" = median(Sepal.Width), 
    "sd" = sd(Sepal.Width), 
    "p10" = quantile(Sepal.Width, probs = 0.1)) %>% 
  mutate(Species = "Total")
  )
```

But I would like something more compact. In particular, I don't want to type the code (for summarize) twice, once for each group and once for the total.

Comment: I know this is a common way to _present_ some information, but generally it is a poor way to _store_ information as the fourth row is a "very different beast" from rows 1-3. I just wanted to put this warning out there...

Comment: I believe your code is only computing each mean only once; do you mean that you don't want to type the code twice, once for each group and once for the total?

Comment: @DanY: Agreed, and very much appreciate your tact and recognition that different people and circumstances have different needs, this is a great example of how to be friendly on SO.

Comment: Yes @Aaron. Thanks.  Will edit to reflect your comment.

Comment: The title's a misnomer, it's really *"How to also compute summary statistics on entire ungrouped dataset, and concatenate total"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it if you untangle what you're trying to do: you have `iris` data that has several species, and you want that summarized along with data for all species. You don't need to calculate those summary stats *before* you can bind. Instead, bind `iris` with a version of `iris` that's been set to `Species = "Total"`, then group and summarize.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  iris,
  iris %>% mutate(Species = "Total")
) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Width),
            Median = median(Sepal.Width),
            sd = sd(Sepal.Width),
            p10 = quantile(Sepal.Width, probs = 0.1))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   Species     Mean Median    sd   p10
#>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa      3.43    3.4 0.379  3   
#> 2 Total       3.06    3   0.436  2.5 
#> 3 versicolor  2.77    2.8 0.314  2.3 
#> 4 virginica   2.97    3   0.322  2.59
```

I like the caution in the comments above, though I have to do this sort of calculation for work enough that I have a similar shorthand function in a personal package. It perhaps makes less sense for things like standard deviations, but it's something I need to do a lot for adding up totals of demographic groups, etc. (If it's useful, that function is [here](https://github.com/camille-s/camiller/blob/master/R/bind_self.R)).

Comment: Thanks @camille!. Best answer so far. I get the comment that this computation requires to store info inefficiently, but I am still surprised that there is no standard function to perform this type of analysis. Makes it harder to convince Stata users to switch.

Answer (score 0):

bit shorter, though quite similar to bind_rows

```
    q10 <- function(x){quantile(x , probs=0.1)}

    iris %>% 
      select(Species,Sepal.Width)%>%
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "q10")) %>% 
      t() %>% 

      cbind(c("total", iris %>% select(Sepal.Width) %>% summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "q10")))) %>% 
      t()
```

more clean probably:

```
  bind_rows( 
    iris %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>%  
      select(Sepal.Width)%>%
      summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "q10"))
    , 
    iris %>% 
      select(Sepal.Width)%>%
      summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "q10")) %>% 
      mutate(Species = "Total")
  )
```